# Laravel: route:cache not use files in subdirectories

Tags: php, laravel, caching, routes

I have a lot of routes in my project and I don't store all web routes in single file, I use subdirectories. 
For example I have standard routes/web.php when I wrote main routes and in this directory I created subdirectory routes/groups. There I have several files separate by some categories. It works fine when I don't use route cache. But if I try create cache by `php artisan route:cache` it creates cache only for standard files like: routes/web.php, routes/channels.php etc.
Even I add require_once on the web.php it doesn't work!
What the problem with route cache?

Laravel version: 5.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Proper way to define routes in a subdirectory is to do it in `RouteServiceProvider.php` file. `php artisan route:cache` will consider these routes then.

In your case, add the following script inside `mapWebRoutes()` function should work:

```php
Route::middleware('web')
    ->namespace($this->namespace)
    ->group(base_path('routes/groups/{your-filename}.php'));
```

You can also assign separate prefix, namespace, assign middleware to every routes file. For instance:

```php
Route::middleware('web')
    ->namespace($this->namespace)
    ->prefix('groups')
    ->group(base_path('routes/groups/{your-filename}.php'));
```

**NOTE:**
`route:cache` won't work with closure based routes. So you have to avoid it in order to use `route:cache`.